# Start() not called on Reloading already Loaded Scenes, only Awake() called in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Whenever I load a new scene the 'first time' the Awake() and Start() methods of the attached script are executed, as expected. But when I switch to another scene (Application.LoadLevel()) and switch back to my previous scene only Awake() is executed but not Start().

I've never experienced such behaviour before Unity5, so is it something new with Unity5 or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

```
public class MyMatchSimulator : MonoBehaviour { 
    void Awake() { 
        Debug.Log("Awake"); 
    } 

    void Start() { 
        Debug.Log("Start"); 
    } 
}
```

On calling `Application.LoadLevel("MyScene");` The first time both `Awake` and `Start` is printed, for subsequent `LoadLevel` calls only `Awake` is printed. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you post related code?

Comment: `public class MyMatchSimulator : MonoBehaviour {
 void Awake(){
  Debug.Log("Awake");
 }

 void Start(){
  Debug.Log("Start");
 }
}`

on calling `Application.LoadLevel("MyScene");`
The first time both Awake and Start is printed, for subsequent LoadLevel calls only Awake is printed. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you'll need to post the code that calls the `LoadLevel` as well.

Comment: Is this a Unity bug ? Which version are you on ? I'm using 4.6.3p1 and I have the same problem, I don't think this is a normal behaviour

Comment: In my case it was caused by some singleton pattern accidently destroying objects on level reload. The pattern `if (instance != null) GameObject.Destroy(this);` is breaking when you reload the same level.